# trying to store the data in local-storage using WebSql

Tags: android, jquery, html

I inserted the values in my html form. Even after successful insertion of data, its not visible in Developers Tools of chrome. Should I check for some setting or is there any cache problem with my browser. My database and tables are created but my values are not getting inserted. I am providing my code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var db = openDatabase("todolist", 1.0, "To Do List Database", 100 * 1024);
     db.transaction(function(transaction) {
         transaction.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list(" + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC," + " name TEXT NOT NULL," + " description TEXT," + " due DATETIME," + " start DATETIME);", []);
     });

     $("#submit").click(function() {
         var name = $("#taskname").val();
         //alert(name);
         var desc = $("#taskdesc").val();
         //alert(desc);
         var due = $("#taskdue").val();
         //alert(due);
         var start = $("#taskstart").val();
         //alert(start);
         db.transaction(function(transaction) {
             var sql = "INSERT INTO list(name,description,due,start )VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
             transaction.executeSql(sql, [name, desc, due, start], function() {

                 alert("Values Inserted")
             }, error);
         });
     });

     function error(transaction, err)

     {
         alert("DB error : " + err.message);
         return false;
     }
 });
```

Comment: are the error or alert being called/displayed?

Comment: alert is only called after the insertion into database takes place successfully,if there is any error then i have called a error function.

Comment: oh and the main problem is this code is running perfectly in my lap, but not in other laptops.So i am confused

Comment: you could add a ';' to after the alert, but I doubt that is an issue

Comment: i tried but as you said its not an issue here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = {};
x.web = {};
db= null;
x.web.open=function()
{
    //alert("hiiii")
    db= openDatabase("amith",1.0,"To Do List Database",100*1024);
}
x.web.create=function()
{
    var data=db;
    //alert(data)
    data.transaction(function(transaction){
    transaction.executeSql(
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS type("+
    "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,"+
    " name TEXT NOT NULL,"+
    " description TEXT,"+
    " due DATETIME,"+
    " start DATETIME)");
    });

}
x.web.addTodo = function(name,desc,due,start) 
    {
        var data1 = db;
        data1.transaction(function(tx){
        var sql="INSERT INTO     
   type(name,description,due,start)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        tx.executeSql(sql,[name,desc,due,start],function(){
        //alert("Values Inserted")
        },error);
        });
    }
 function error (transaction, err) 

    {
        alert ("DB error : " + err.message);
        return false;
    }

function init()
{
    x.web.open();
    x.web.create();
}
 function addTodo() 
{
    //alert("toodod")
    var name = document.getElementById("taskname").value;
    var desc= document.getElementById("taskdesc").value;
    var due= document.getElementById("taskdue").value;
    var start=document.getElementById("taskstart").value
    //alert(name);
    x.web.addTodo(name,desc,due,start);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I was able to get those commands to work on a test DB so I am guessing you either have one of two issues.  Either one of your values (name, desc, due, start) is undefined or you need to add a ';' to your insert command

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO list(name,description,due,start )VALUES(?,?,?,?);";
```

instead of

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO list(name,description,due,start )VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: can u clear one more doubt of mine.The code is working properly on my laptop, but when i copy/paste the same code to another laptop the values get inserted only ones after that i have to wait for say 5 min to enter  data  again into it.Does that mean i have some browser problem or something else?

Comment: Is it running on different browsers?  Could be a difference, but that would be weird.  Did you try with the extra ';' in the sql command, because that could be causing a delay/issue.

Comment: I am running only in chrome.Firefox is not supporting localstorage. I did try with that etxra';' but still not working.

Comment: It might be in the chrome settings on the second computer.  There are probably ways to turn off web storage.  Did you have an issue running it on an Android device?

Comment: @Amith were you able to find the issue at all?  the web standard should be similar over different browsers.

Comment: @MikeIsraelI am thinking of modifying the whole code itself.I am thinking it will work better if i use functions to call  each operation of  creating and inserting procedures

Comment: @Amith great to hear, you should post your corrected code as an answer so that others can benefit from it was well if you can.